# Where is the http.get() function in Angular2 defined?

Tags: http, typescript, angular

I'm new to Typescript and Angular 2.

I wanted to look at the exact implementation of `http.get()`, so I opened the file in `./node_modules/angular2/src/http/http.d.ts` and scrolled to the `get` function. This is what I found:

```
    /**
     * Performs a request with `get` http method.
     */
    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>;
    /**
     * Performs a request with `post` http method.
     */
    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>;
    /**
....
```

Basically, there is no function definition. It seems like an abstract method (in Java lingo). I looked through the other `http` files, used VSCode intellisense, and couldn't find the code for the body of the function.

Where is it and how can I find it?

Comment: You are looking at a declaration (the `.d` in `.d.ts` indicates that) file : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts

What you are seeing is the TypeScript typings file. It contains the definitions, but not the implementation.